# Pipeline failing with error "The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

How to resolve this issue, my pipeline output -
[image]

I tried setting the Path in my gitlab-ci.yml file as -
[image]

I also tried setting the Path variable from the gitlab-runner configuration file "config.toml" -[image]

Comment: Please include error reports as text, rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question:

> Pipeline failing with error "The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..." — How to resolve this issue?

Issue resolution lies within the connection of the ability `git` being a *cmdlet* in Powershell. As you can [learn. microsoft. com.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?view=powershell-7.3) it certainly never is. Therefore the diagnostic message alone is not the whole question and an answer might be misleading:

Establish `git` as a command so that Powershell does not try to locate a cmdlet instead.

---

It starts by using the absolute path to the executable and replace the base-name `git` with it.

Then verify the executable is the program you want to actually make use of.

Then consider if not using the absolute pathname already suffices. If so, or if understanding `PATH` and it's value is too cumbersome to handle in your current situation, continue using the absolute pathname, there is enough time left to change it sometime in the future.

Otherwise the rules are relatively basic, and it started like this back in the DOS days and the early days of COMMAND.COM, so perhaps [kb35284](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35284) marks an historic starting point. Otherwise the vendors documentation of your powershell should ship with more current information actually useful to learn about (see link above for the website and select the resources according to your level of understanding, e.g. the [PowerShell Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/)).